# Laravel Vue Js API POST request to add items to cart returns an empty cart on subsequent fetch

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, vuejs3

I'm developing a Laravel application with an API endpoint for adding items to a cart. The cart is populated successfully when adding items, but when I fetch the cart items using another API endpoint, it returns an empty cart.

Here are the details of my setup:

- Laravel Framework 10.13.5
- Frontend Framework Vue.js vue@3.2.36

`CartController.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\BackOffice;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Product;
use App\Models\Customer;
use Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\Facades\Cart;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;


class CartController extends Controller
{


    public function addToCart(Request $request)
    {

        Cart::add([
            'id' => $request->input('product_id'),
            'name' => $request->input('product_name'),
            'qty' => $request->qty,
            'price' => $request->input('selling_price'),
            'weight' => 10,
//            'options' => ['size' => 'large']
        ]);

        $c = Cart::content();

        dd($c);

        return response()->json(['message' => 'Product Added Successfully']);
    }


    public function __invoke(Request $request)
    {

        dump(session()->all());


        $cartItems = Cart::content(); // Retrieve cart items from your data source

        return response()->json($cartItems);
    }
}
```

`api.php`

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\BackOffice\POSController;
use App\Http\Controllers\BackOffice\CategoryController;
use App\Http\Controllers\BackOffice\CartController;


Route::get('/pos/products', POSController::class);
Route::get('/pos/categories', CategoryController::class);
Route::get('/cart-items', CartController::class);
Route::post('/add-to-cart', [CartController::class, 'addToCart']);
```

`ProductComponent`

```
<script setup>
import axios from "axios"
import { ref, onMounted, computed } from "vue"

const products = ref([])
const categories = ref([])
const selectedCategory = ref(null)
const searchQuery = ref('');
const cartItems = ref([]);
const csrfToken = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content');

axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = csrfToken;



const getProducts = () => {
    axios
        .get("/api/pos/products")
        .then((res) => (products.value = res.data))
        .catch((error) => console.log(error))
}

const getCategories = () => {
    axios
        .get("/api/pos/categories")
        .then((res) => (categories.value = res.data))
        .catch((error) => console.log(error))
}

onMounted(() => {
    getProducts()
    getCategories()

})

// Computed property to filter products by selected category
const filteredProducts = computed(() => {
    let filtered = products.value;

    if (selectedCategory.value) {
        filtered = filtered.filter((product) => product.category_id === selectedCategory.value.id);
    }

    const search = searchQuery.value.toLowerCase();

    return filtered.filter((product) => {
        const productName = product.product_name.toLowerCase();
        const productCode = product.product_code.toLowerCase();
        const categoryName = product.category?.category_name.toLowerCase() || '';

        return (
            productName.includes(search) ||
            productCode.includes(search) ||
            categoryName.includes(search)
        );
    });
});
const addToCart = (product) => {
    axios.post("/api/add-to-cart", {
            _token: '{{ csrf_token() }}',
            product_id: product.id,
            product_name: product.product_name,
            qty: 1,
            selling_price: product.selling_price
        })
        .then((response) => {
            console.log(response.data.message); // Product added to cart
            // Handle any other logic after adding the product to the cart
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error("Failed to add product to cart:", error);
            // Handle the error case
        });
};
</script>
<template>
    <div class="product-area" >
        <div class="accesories" >
            <div class="side-indicator">
                <button class="btn" :class="{ 'active-btn': !selectedCategory }" type="button" @click="selectedCategory = null">All</button>
                <div v-for="category in categories" :key="category.id">
                    <button class="btn" :class="{ 'active-btn': selectedCategory && selectedCategory.id === category.id }" type="button" @click="selectedCategory = category">{{ category.category_name }}</button>
                </div>
            </div>

<!--            <div class="side-indicator">-->

<!--                <button class="btn active-btn mt-0" type="button">All</button>-->
<!--                <div v-for="category in categories" :key="category.id">-->
<!--                    <button class="btn" type="button" @click="selectedCategory = category">{{ category.category_name }}</button>-->
<!--                </div>-->

<!--            </div>-->
            <div class="item-area">
                <div class="item-top-area top-area">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                            <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span>
                        </div>
                        <input id="monId" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Name or code or category" v-model="searchQuery">
                    </div>

                    <div class="edit-icon">
                        <button class="btn fa-btn" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addItemBox"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="mob-btns">
                    <button class="btn btn-green" type="button">Category</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-green active-btn ml-auto float-right" type="button">Product</button>
                </div>
                <div class="item-area-box row mx-0">
                    <div class="col-6 col-md-4 px-1" v-for="product in filteredProducts" :key="product.id">
                        <div class="item-box mt-0 text-center" data-toggle="modal" @click="addToCart(product)">
                            <div class="txt-box">
                                <span>Ksh {{ product.selling_price }}</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="img-box">
                                <img src="{{ product.product_image }}" class="img-fluid" alt="">
                            </div>
                            <div class="txt-box item-name">
                                <span>{{ product.product_name }}</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

`CartCompnent`

```
<script>

    import axios from 'axios';
    
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                cartItems: [],
            };
        },
        mounted() {
            this.fetchCartItems();
        },
        methods: {
            fetchCartItems() {
                axios.get('/api/cart-items')
                    .then(response => {
                        this.cartItems = response.data;
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        console.error(error);
                    });
            },
        },
    };
    </script>
<template>


    <div class="col-xl-6 px-1">
        <div class="top-area-btns d-xl-none">
            <div class="show-on-mob text-center">
                <a href="#calculationArea" class="btn btn-green active-btn" type="button"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> Cart</a>
                <a href="#productArea" class="btn btn-green" type="button"><i class="fa fa-shopping-bag"></i> Product</a>
            </div>
            <div class="right-part">
                <button class="btn btn-green" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#allSaleModal"><i class="fa fa-history"></i> <span>Your all sales</span></button>
                <button class="btn btn-green" type="button"><i class="fa fa-tachometer"></i> <span>Dashboard</span></button>
                <button class="btn btn-green" type="button"><i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i> <span>Logout</span></button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="calculationArea" class="calculation-area">
            <div class="top-area">
                <div class="input-group">
                    
                </div>
                <div class="edit-icon">
                    <button class="btn fa-btn" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editCustomer"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button>
                    <button class="btn fa-btn" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addCustomer"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="cart-table">
                <table class="table">
                    <thead class="">
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">Item</th>
                        <th scope="col">Price</th>
                        <th scope="col">Qty/Amt</th>
<!--                        <th scope="col">Discount</th>-->
                        <th scope="col">Total</th>
                        <th scope="col">Edit/Del</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <tr v-if="cartItems.length === 0">
                        <td colspan="5" class="text-center">
                            <h3>Add Items, Your Cart is empty</h3>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr v-for="item in cartItems" :key="item.id" class="table-row">
                        <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
                        <td>Ksh {{ item.price }}</td>
                        <td class="inc-dec">
                            <button class="btn value-button" id="decrease" onclick="decreaseValue()" value="Decrease Value">-</button>
                            <input class="form-control" type="" id="number" value="{{ item.qty }}" />
                            <button class="btn value-button" id="increase" onclick="increaseValue()" value="Increase Value">+</button>
                        </td>
                        <td><input type="" class="form-control" placeholder="Discount"></td>
<!--                        <td>15,120</td>-->
                        <td class="edit-btn">
                            <button type="button" class="btn fa-btn editme"  data-target="#productBox" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Edit me">
                                <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
                            </button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn fa-btn delme" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Delete me">
                                <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
                            </button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="final-calculation">
                <table class="table">
                    <tbody>
                    <tr class="table-row">
                        <td>
                            <table class="table mini-table mb-0">
                                <tbody>
                                <tr class="table-row">
                                    <td>Total Item: <span>0</span></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td><i class="fa fa-file fa-green" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#typeNoteBox"></i></td>
                                    <td><input type="" class="form-control" placeholder="Reference no."></td>
                                </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                        <td>Sub Total</td>
                        <td>tk <span>0.00</span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="table-row">
                        <td class="pl-3 d-flex align-items-baseline"><i class="fa fa-calendar fa-green mr-2"></i> <input type="text" class="form-control datepicker" placeholder="DD-MM-YYYY"></td>
                        <td>Discount</td>
                        <td><input type="" class="form-control"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="table-row">
                        <td></td>
                        <td>Total Discount</td>
                        <td>tk <span>0.00</span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="table-row">
                        <td></td>
                        <td>Shipping/Other</td>
                        <td><input type="" class="form-control"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="table-row">
                        <td></td>
                        <td>Total Payable</td>
                        <td>tk <span>0.00</span></td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="calculator">
                <div class="displayBox">
                    <p class="displayText" id="display">0</p>
                </div>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td><button class="btn clear hvr-back-pulse" id="clear">C</button></td>
                        <td><button class="btn btn-calc hvr-radial-out" id="sqrt">√</button></td>
                        <td><button class="btn btn-calc hvr-radial-out hvr-radial-out" id="square">x<sup>2</sup></button></td>
                        <td><button id="divide" class="btn btn-operation hvr-fade">÷</button></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><button class="btn btn-calc hvr-radial-out" id="seven">7</button></td>
                        <td><button class="btn btn-calc hvr-radial-out" id="eight">8</button></td>
                        <td><button class="btn btn-calc hvr-radial-out" id="nine">9</button></td>
                        <td><button id="multiply" class="btn btn-operation hvr-fade">×</button></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><button class="btn btn-calc hvr-radial-out" id="four">4</button></td>
                        <td><button class="btn btn-calc hvr-radial-out" id="five">5</button></td>
                        <td><button class="btn btn-calc hvr-radial-out" id="six">6</button></td>
                        <td><button id="subtract" class="btn btn-operation hvr-fade">−</button></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><button class="btn btn-calc hvr-radial-out" id="one">1</button></td>
                        <td><button class="btn btn-calc hvr-radial-out" id="two">2</button></td>
                        <td><button class="btn btn-calc hvr-radial-out" id="three">3</button></td>
                        <td><button id="add" class="btn btn-operation hvr-fade">+</button></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><button class="btn btn-calc hvr-radial-out" id="zero">0</button></td>
                        <td><button class="btn btn-calc hvr-radial-out" id="decimal">.</button></td>
                        <td class="equal"><button id="equals" class="btn btn-operation equals hvr-back-pulse">=</button></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bottom-area-btns">
            <button class="btn btn-1 calculator-btn" type="button"><i class="fa fa-calculator"></i> Calculator</button>
            <button class="btn btn-green" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#"><i class="fa fa-keyboard-o"></i> Keyboard</button>
            <button class="btn btn-3" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#holdSaleModal"><i class="fa fa-folder-open"></i> Hold Sales</button>
            <button class="btn btn-4" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#"><i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i> Cancel</button>
            <button class="btn btn-yellow" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#holdBox"><i class="fa fa-hand-rock-o"></i> Hold</button>
            <button class="btn btn-6" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#paymentModal"><i class="fa fa-credit-card"></i> Payment</button>
            <button class="btn btn-7" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#holdBox"><i class="fa fa-hand-rock-o"></i> Hold</button>
        </div>
    </div>

</template>
```

I have thoroughly checked my code and verified that the items are being added to the cart successfully in the `addToCart` method of the `CartController`. I can confirm this by dumping the cart contents and observing the correct items and quantities.

However, when I make subsequent requests to fetch the cart items using the __invoke method of the `CartController`, the returned result is an empty cart. The response does not include any items, even though I expect the previously added items to be present.

I have also inspected the session configuration and confirmed that the session driver is set correctly. Additionally, I have double-checked that the cart items are being stored in the session.

I'm seeking guidance on how to troubleshoot this issue and resolve it. I would appreciate any insights, suggestions, or code examples that can help me identify the cause and fix the problem.

Thank you in advance for your assistance and expertise!

Comment: Can you sort that code better?

Comment: @Tpojka Sorting is done

Comment: How will the __invoke method supposed to return the requested cart content? There is no any session info. assigned for the cart. Will the `Cart::content()` method grabs the session data by default? If yes then too, how will it find the right cart unless there is no session info stored in the cart?

Comment: Have you tried with regular method instead of magic (`__invoke()`) method? For that matter, when invoke method is used, controller is usually one (that) method class. Try and check if there is the difference in behavior.

Comment: I agree with @Tpojka.  Invokable controller are single responsibility means you shouldn’t have multiple methods there. If you want to use different method then define the methods name and use it in your routes accordingly like addToCart.

Comment: Hello,

Could you show your code of " Route::get('/cart-items', CartController::class); " . And is data saving in session or in DB?